# How to loop through a controller based on product_id in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have these models in my Laravel-5.8

Product Model:

```
class Product extends Model
{
   protected $fillable = [
              'id',
              'name',
            ];
  public function invoice(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Invoice');
 }
}
```

Invoice Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Invoice extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
              'id',
              'customer_id',
              'product_id',
              'invoice_date',
              'qty',
      'price',
          ];
    public function customer(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Customer');
    }
    public function product(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product');
    }
}
```

Each invoice has one or more products.

Invoice Controller

```
public function create()
{
    $customers = Customer::all();
    $products = Product::all();
    return view('invoice.create', compact('customers','products'));
}

public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([

        'customer_id' => 'required',
        'product_id' => 'required',
        'qty' => 'required',
        'price' => 'required',
    ]);

    $invoice = new Invoice();
    $invoice->customer_id = $request->customer_id;

    .....

     return redirect('invoice/'.$invoice->id)->with('message','invoice created Successfully');
}
```

Invoice: create.blade

```
                    <form  method="POST" action="{{route('invoice.store')}}">
                        @csrf
                        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                            <label class="control-label">Customer Name</label>
                            <select name="customer_id" class="form-control">
                                <option>Select Customer</option>
                                @foreach($customers as $customer)
                                    <option name="customer_id" value="{{$customer->id}}">{{$customer->name}} </option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>                            </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                            <label class="control-label">Date</label>
                            <input name="invoice_date"  class="form-control datepicker"  value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d')?>" type="date" placeholder="Enter date">
                        </div>

                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">Product Name</th>
                            <th scope="col">Qty</th>
                            <th scope="col">Price</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td><select name="product_id[]" class="form-control productname" >
                                    <option>Select Product</option>
                                @foreach($products as $product)
                                        <option name="product_id[]" value="{{$product->id}}">{{$product->name}}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="qty[]" class="form-control qty" ></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="price[]" class="form-control price" ></td>
                         </tr>
                        </tbody>

                    </table>

                        <div >
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                 </form>
```

From the diagram below:

[image: invoice]

Product_id, qty, price are arrays.
I want the controller to iterate and count the number of products, then the rows of product_id, qty and price in the view will be based on count of products. And then everything will be saved in the invoice table.

How do I complete my store controller code to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
$products = $request->get('product_id');
$qte = $request->get('qty');
$price = $request->get('price');
foreach($products as $key=>$product){
    $invoice =Invoice::creeate([
        'product_id' => $product,
        'qte' => $qte[$key],
        'price' => $price[$key],
        ...
    ]);
```

}

Comment: or use for loop to replace $key to $i

Comment: But you should make a new model call it ' invoice_details ' as belongs to invoice and replace in my code invoice to invoice_details or use hasmany methods

Comment: But how do I make the to have rows based on the product count in the database. For instance, if there are seven (7)  products, the array will be 7. There will be seven (7) rows.

Comment: exaclty but the problem here you should have only 1 for invoice for that make invoice_detail model with this field : invoice_id , product_id, qte, price, and invoice with id and customers info

Comment: or you can change type of product field to json (array) with add casts in invoice model for product ... fields